# smtp.lua:80: attempt to call field 'b64' (a nil value) when trying to send an email using lua socket

Tags: email, lua, smtp, luasocket, luasec

So I tried sending an email using the luasocket smtp function with ssl but for some reason I get this error `/usr/local/share/lua/5.1/socket/smtp.lua:80: attempt to call field 'b64' (a nil value)` I have all the libraries downloaded and I don't know why it doesn't work.
This is my code

```lua
local smtp = require("socket.smtp")
local ssl = require('ssl')
local https = require 'ssl.https'
local mime = require("mime")
function sslCreate()
    local sock = socket.tcp()
    return setmetatable({
        connect = function(_, host, port)
            local r, e = sock:connect(host, port)
            if not r then return r, e end
            sock = ssl.wrap(sock, {mode='client', protocol='tlsv1'})
            return sock:dohandshake()
        end
    }, {
        __index = function(t,n)
            return function(_, ...)
                return sock[n](sock, ...)
            end
        end
    })
end
local k, e = smtp.send{
                from = "[REDACTED]",
                rcpt = self.params.email,
                user = "[REDACTED]",
                password = "[REDACTED]",
                port = 465,
                server = "smtp.gmail.com",
                source = smtp.message(message),
                create = sslCreate
            }
            if not k then
                print(e)
            end
```

Answer (score 1):

The code on line 80 calls `mime.b64()` function, with `mime` being the result of `require "mime"` call (where mime module comes from the luasocket library). Unless there is something wrong with the mime module itself (and if it came from the correct source and was properly installed, there shouldn't be), it's most likely caused by `mime.lua` file available somewhere in `package.path`, so it gets loaded instead of the actual module.

If you want to troubleshoot it further, just review the result of `require "mime"` in the debugger or use `package.searchpath("mime", package.path)` to see what is being picked up ([searchpath](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.4/manual.html#pdf-package.searchpath)); you may also need to try it with `package.cpath`.